# AsyncStorage en React Native: para una determinada clave debo actualizar su valor compuesto por un arreglo de objetos

Tags: react-native, async-storage

A través del uso de **AsyncStorage**, he almacenado el siguiente arreglo de objetos como valor de una clave llamada "Taller", hasta aquí sin problemas.

```
const automotores = [{
    reparaciones: [
        {
            fecha: "15/04/21",
            detalles: {
                nombre: "Alberto",
                marca: "Ford",        
                modelo: "Mondeo",
                kilometraje: "28456",
                telefono: "12345678" 
            },
            observaciones: "Amortiguadores"
        }
    ],
    detalles: "Turnos por la mañana"
}];


// Almacenamiento local
try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("Taller", JSON.stringify(automotores[0]))
} catch(e) {
    console.log("Se produjo un Error.");
    return;
}
console.log("Datos guardados!")
```

*Mi consulta es **¿cómo debería hacer para agregar un nuevo item al valor almacenado?***

Por ejemplo el siguiente:

```
// Nuevo item a incorporar
const nuevaCarga = {
    fecha: "19/04/21",
    detalles: {
        nombre: "Micaela",
        marca: "Volkswagen",        
        modelo: "Vento",
        kilometraje: "17234",
        telefono: "87654321" 
    },
    observaciones: "Tapizado"
};
```

Desearía que el valor almacenado quedara así:

```
// Valor actualizado de la clave "Taller"
const automotores = [{
    reparaciones: [
        {
            fecha: "15/04/21",
            detalles: {
                nombre: "Alberto",
                marca: "Ford",        
                modelo: "Mondeo",
                kilometraje: "28456",
                telefono: "12345678" 
            },
            observaciones: "Amortiguadores"
        },
        {
            fecha: "19/04/21",
            detalles: {
                nombre: "Micaela",
                marca: "Volkswagen",        
                modelo: "Vento",
                kilometraje: "17234",
                telefono: "87654321" 
            },
            observaciones: "Tapizado" 
        }
    ],
    detalles: "Turnos por la mañana"
}];
```

Entiendo que quizás debería hacerse a través del uso de AsyncStorage.mergeItem(), pero realmente no encuentro el modo de incorporar más información al valor existente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te sugiero que utilices [el método `push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) para agregar valores a un array, tomando esto en cuenta solo debes de:

1. Obtener el valor de tu llave `Taller` por medio de `AsyncStorage.getItem('Taller')`.
2. Parsear el valor y guardar sus contenidos en una variable.
3. Acceder al array en la variable.
4. Utilizar el método `push` para agregar el nuevo elemento `nuevaCarga`.
5. Guardar el nuevo elemento por medio de `AsyncStorage.setItem()`

Te dejo un ejemplo simulando AsyncStorage *de manera casera*:

```js
//Esto es solo para simular el método original (No es asincrónico), puedes ignorar esta primera parte.
const AsyncStorage = (() => {
  let data = {};

  function getItem(key) {
    return data[key];
  }

  function setItem(key, value) {
    console.log(`Se ha guardadlo la llave ${key} con el valor: ${value}`);
    data[key] = value;
  }

  return {
    getItem: getItem,
    setItem: setItem
  }

})();


const automotores = [{
  reparaciones: [{
    fecha: "15/04/21",
    detalles: {
      nombre: "Alberto",
      marca: "Ford",
      modelo: "Mondeo",
      kilometraje: "28456",
      telefono: "12345678"
    },
    observaciones: "Amortiguadores"
  }],
  detalles: "Turnos por la mañana"
}];

const nuevaCarga = {
  fecha: "19/04/21",
  detalles: {
    nombre: "Micaela",
    marca: "Volkswagen",
    modelo: "Vento",
    kilometraje: "17234",
    telefono: "87654321"
  },
  observaciones: "Tapizado"
};

//Guardamos la llave con los valores iniciales
AsyncStorage.setItem("Taller", JSON.stringify(automotores[0]));

//Ahora seguimos los pasos descritos

//1.Obtenemos el valor de la llave y 2. lo paresamos y lo guardamos en una variable (Recuerda usar el await en tu código, el ejemplo que cree no es asincrónico)

const valorTaller = JSON.parse(AsyncStorage.getItem("Taller"));

//3. Acccedemos el array de la variable y 4.le agregamos el nuevo elemento con el método push

valorTaller.reparaciones.push(nuevaCarga);

//Podemos revisar que efectivamente se haya guardado el nuevo valor en el objeto por medio de un console.log:
console.log(valorTaller);

//5.Guardamos el elemento nuevamente con el método que usamos al inicio
AsyncStorage.setItem("Taller", JSON.stringify(valorTaller));
```

Comment: He resuelto el inconveniente utilizando tus indicaciones @FranAcuna. Muy agradecido.